# what is "Minimal Uncountable well-ordered set"?

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone make me understand what is "Minimal Uncountable well-ordered set" (Munkres, Topology, Example 2 of the limit point compactness section)?

I know what is Uncountablity and Well ordered set.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: An ordered set order-isomorphic to the first uncountable ordinal?

Comment: I think context will be needed

Comment: Can you please explain in simple terms?@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: There are four concepts involved in your question. Do you know what a set is? Do you know what it means for it to be well-ordered? Do you know what it means for a set to be uncountable? Do you know what minimal (in this context) means? If you clarify where your difficulty is, there is a greater chance you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: I know the meaning of every terms But I found it difficult to understand when they are together.@IttayWeiss

Comment: So $\mathbb R$ is not well ordered minimal uncountable set for sure.. As  we remove an element , It still remains uncountable...So can you give me a concrete example of $S_{\Omega}$?@IttayWeiss

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps what you might be missing is a theorem of set theory which says (roughly speaking) that any set of well ordered sets is well ordered.

To be precise, suppose that ${\cal A} =\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a set, each of whose elements $A_i$ is a well ordered set, and let's suppose that no two elements of ${\cal A}$ are order isomorphic (i.e. for all $i \ne j \in I$ there does not exist an order preserving bijection between $A_i$ and $A_j$). Let's define a relation on ${\cal A}$, where $A_i  < A_j$ means that there exists an order preserving injection $f : A_i \to A_j$.

- **Theorem:** This relation is a well-ordering on ${\cal A}$. Therefore, ${\cal A}$ has a minimal element.

So, to say that a well-ordered set $A$ is a "minimimal uncountable well ordered set" simply means that for any set ${\cal A}$ of uncountable well-ordered sets, no two of which are order isomorphic, if $A \in {\cal A}$ then $A$ is the minimal element of ${\cal A}$.

There are a few more theorems to ponder which help to iron out the understanding of this concept:

- **Theorem:** Suppose $A$ is an uncountable well ordered set, and suppose that for each $b \in A$ the set $\{a \in A \mid a < b\}$ is countable. Then $A$ is a minimal uncountable well ordered set.
- **Theorem:** Any two minimal uncountable well ordered sets are order isomorphic. (So it is fair to speak about *the* minimal uncountable well ordered set, because it is unique up to order isomorphism)

For a more concrete example of this concept, the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is the "minimal infinite well ordered set": for any set ${\cal A}$ of well ordered infinite sets (no two of which are order isomorphic), if $\mathbb{N} \in {\cal A}$ then $\mathbb{N}$ is the minimal element of ${\cal A}$. The other theorems mentioned have analogues here:

- **Theorem:** If $A$ is an infinite well ordered set, and if for each $b \in A$ the set $\{a \in A \mid a < b\}$ is finite, then $A$ is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.
- **Theorem:** Any minimal infinite well ordered set is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So $\mathbb R$ is not well ordered minimal uncountable set for sure.. As  we remove an element , It still remains uncountable...So can you give me a concrete example of $S_{\Omega}$?@Lee Mosher

Comment: @cmi : Where is there an "$S_\Omega$" anywhere on this page?

Comment: If you have something else to ask that is related to this question and answer, it is best that you ask it in a new and fully formulated question, instead of asking it in a comment with new notation, which very few people will stumble across, and fewer still will understand.

Answer (score 2):

@cmi ℝ in the usual ordering is not well ordered. And if equipped with proper ordering, ℝ *can* be isomorphic to the "Minimal Uncountable well-ordered set" (assuming the continuum hypothesis), because under the continuum hypothesis, ℝ has the same cardinality as the "Minimal Uncountable well-ordered set", and therefore a bijection between them exists. We can then just define the ordering on ℝ based on the bijection and the ordering of the "Minimal Uncountable well-ordered set".

So the reason of ℝ (with the usual ordering) being "not well ordered minimal uncountable set" is not the reason you gave (can remove element), but the its ordering.