# There exists a minimal uncountable well ordered set.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

There exists a well-ordered set $A$ having a largest element $\Omega$ such that the section $S_\Omega$ of $A$  by $\Omega$ is uncountable but every other section is countable.

Can anyone make me understand this theorem?

I can not understand what Mukres has tried to say  in his Topology's Book.. I can  not visualize what Mukresh has said in the proof.  I can not understand why we always get an element $\Omega$ such that the section less than $\Omega$ is countable. What ensures the availability of $\Omega$ in a uncountable well ordered set?

Can anyone make me understand with proper example?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: How do you visualize very large countable well orders?

Comment: "very large " countable well order means? @AsafKaragila

Comment: You have answered your own question perfectly in the first sentence of your post. There is only one example (up to isomorphism) and you have described it exactly.

Comment: I am trying to prove that statement..@bof

Comment: The set $A$ you described is not quite the **minimal** uncountable well-ordered set, that is the section $S_\Omega$ of $A$.

Comment: I meant I can not visualize how there exists a number $\Omega$ which is greater than only a countable number of elelments.@bof

Comment: Your question was not about how to **prove** that statement, was it?

Comment: Is $S_\Omega$ not minimal?@bof

Comment: Yea...I want to prove the statement. Mukresh proved it . I could not understand it.@bof

Comment: Yes, $S_\Omega$ is a minimal uncountable well-ordered set. The set $A=S_\Omega\cup\{\Omega\}$ is not minimal.

Comment: Yea I understood that. But can you tell me about the proof?@bof

Comment: I meant I can not visualize how there exists a number $\Omega$ which is greater than only a countable number of elelments.@AsafKaragila

Comment: Why you are being so unkind to my question? I did not find any similarity with that link. Please explain how those questions are similar?@AsafKaragila

Comment: Please reopen the question or explain how they are similar? You can not abuse your power. Please...I am really in need to understand this.@AsafKaragila

Comment: Aren't you asking for a proof that uncountable ordinals exist? Why is there "kindness" involved here? It has nothing to do with kindness. Calling Munkres by Mukresh repeatedly is unkind, by the way.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745911/what-is-minimal-uncountable-well-ordered-set might be a better duplicate, or perhaps in conjunction with the current one.